# Reading specific columns from DBF (Visual FoxPro) file in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, dbf

I have been using [DbfDataReader](https://github.com/yellowfeather/DbfDataReader) to read DBF files in my C# application. So far, I can read column name, column index, and iterate through the records successfully. There does not appear to be a way to read specific column data I'd like without using the column index. For example, I can get at the FIRSTNAME value with a statement like:

```
using DbfDataReader;    
var dbfPath = "/CONTACTS.DBF";
using (var dbfTable = new DbfTable(dbfPath, EncodingProvider.UTF8))
{
     var dbfRecord = new DbfRecord(dbfTable);
     while (dbfTable.Read(dbfRecord))
     {
          Console.WriteLine(dbfRecord.Values[1].ToString()); // would prefer to use something like dbfRecord.Values["FIRSTNAME"].ToString()
          Console.WriteLine(dbfRecord.Values[2].ToString()); // would prefer to use something like dbfRecord.Values["LASTNAME"].ToString()
     }
  }
```

Where **1** is the index of the FIRSTNAME column and **2** is the index of the LASTNAME column. Is there anyway to use "FIRSTNAME" (or the column name) as the key (or accessor) for what is essentially a name/value pair? My goal is to get all of the columns I care about without having to first build this map each time. (Please forgive me if the terms I am using are not exactly right).

Thanks so much for taking a look at this...

Comment: You can use the DbfDataReader class that implements the reader[name] pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DbfDataReader class as below:

```
var dbfPath = "/CONTACTS.DBF";
var options = new DbfDataReaderOptions
{
    SkipDeletedRecords = true,
    Encoding = EncodingProvider.UTF8
};

using (var dbfDataReader = new DbfDataReader.DbfDataReader(dbfPath, options))
{
    while (dbfDataReader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dbfDataReader["FIRSTNAME"])
        Console.WriteLine(dbfDataReader["LASTNAME"])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this @ChrisR. This is super straightforward. The only issue is that I am getting the following error: 'DbfDataReader' is a namespace but is used like a type -- I have the right using statement I believe: using DbfDataReader;. I also have using (var dbfDataReader = new DbfDataReader(dbfPath, options));

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks so much! I appreciate it. One more question. With dbfRecord, I was able to check IsDeleted to see if the record was deleted. Is that possible also with dbfDataReader?

Comment: Found it... `dbfDataReader.DbfRecord.isDeleted` @ChrisR: Thanks so much for such a great library and your responsiveness to my request for help!!

Comment: Is there any way to check if a column exists before trying to access it? For example, dbfDataReader["HappinessScore"] will return, 
threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' if "HappinessScore" is not a column in the table... but I can't figure out how to check for it....

Comment: You can specify whether to skip deleted records in the options, I've updated the answer above.

Comment: You can get the columns via the DbfTable e.g. to get the column names `dbfDataReader.DbfTable.DbfColumns.Select(col => col.Name).ToList()`. You'd want to do this outside the while loop

Comment: Second that - Using namespaces and classes with same name might make a lot of confusion. If you're using it a lot, you can create class that inherits from DbfDataReader.DbfDataReader and copy-in all the constructors, and use new class to avoid always fully qualifying it.